# Find and replace keyword in a string with PHP

Tags: php

I have this code to find and replace some string if it's between some `{{` and `}}`.

```
$string = 'This is my {{important keyword}}.';
$string = preg_replace('/{{(.*?)}}/', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $string);
return $string;
```

How I can change the `<a href="$1">$1</a>` part to have something like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com/important-keyword">important keyword</a>
```

So the `href` needs to have the `match` item converted like a slug (words separated with a dash, no accent or special char).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to allow change on matches in a function.

See also `use($url)` to allow the function to access to the external variable.

Code:

```php
$url = 'https://example.com';
$string = 'This is my {{important keyword}}.';

$string = preg_replace_callback('/{{(.*?)}}/', function($matches) use ($url) {
    $newURL = $url . '/' . str_replace(' ', '-', $matches[1]);
    return '<a href="' . $newURL . '">' . htmlentities($matches[1]) . '</a>';
}, $string);

echo $string;
```

Output:

```
This is my <a href="https://example.com/important-keyword">important keyword</a>.
```